# Objective-C: Exclamation Point strcmp in "if" statement

Tags: objective-c, strcmp

I am looking over some OpenGL ES code to multiplay matrices, but I'm not sure about how this  if statement works:

```
for (int i = 0; i <_uniformArraySize; i++) {
    **if (!strcmp(_uniformArray[i].Name, "ModelViewProjectionMatrix")) {**

        GLKMatrix4 modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(_projectionMatrix, _modelViewMatrix);
glUniformMatrix4fv(_uniformArray[i].Location, 1, GL_FALSE, modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    }
}
```

Does !strcmp mean that the strings are equal or not equal? I looked at the strcmp documentation and it returns numbers. So how does this exclamation point in an if statement affect a number (being the return value of strcmp)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Objective C, like C, allows integers in conditionals, using `!expr` is a common shorthand for `expr== 0`.

Your statement is equivalent to

```
if (strcmp(_uniformArray[i].Name, "ModelViewProjectionMatrix") == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Since [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) returns zero when strings are equal to each other, the condition checks if the content of two C strings is the same.

Answer (score 0):

strcmp() function returns the total number of differences found between each string, so a zero means there are no differences.  It is kind of un-intuitive when you think of it in terms of strcmp true/false.

The exclamation mark is the 'NOT' operator.  This means that it will test whether the value in front of it is NOT true, so the result is essentially a reversal of the original boolean value.

In this case, if !strcmp() means if the result of strcmp is NOT > 0 then the result is true.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` will return zero when strings are equal. The exclamation point is the negation operator so the program will enter the `if` statement when strings are equal.